Using 4 characters to represent future Epoch time and compare to current day
I would like to ask for best practices or ways to improve my code for my very specific problem I am solving which involves taking a 4 character limited length string to represent a future date it could be one week from now or a month etc. And comparing it to the present day, then doing something if too many days have passed.
I think I am able to do this by creating a string that always starts with "17", inserting the four digits and padding the rest with four zeros, I don't need this to be super accurate just within a day or so.
A couple things to note:

I am aware of the possibility of the user manually changing the date in their iphone settings. I plan to check for a server date in the future and compare a second time but this is a mostly an offline app

The 4 character string I am receiving I am the one who will input this string into a bluetooth peripheral data field. The string retains the ability to be letters or not all numbers in the future, so I am first checking if all the characters are integers before turning it into a date

My code is probably not the most efficient

This probably sounds like a stupid problem but that is the parameters I am working with
if let reservationDate = node?.user?.dateValue {
 let arr = Array(reservationDate)
   //I am checking whether the index exists probably unnecessary but being overly cautious
   if arr.indices.contains(0) {
    if let char1 = Int(String(arr[0])){
     if arr.indices.contains(1) {
      if let char2 = Int(String(arr[1])){
       if arr.indices.contains(2) {
        if let char3 = Int(String(arr[2])){
         if arr.indices.contains(3) {
          if let char4 = Int(String(arr[3])){
             let deviceValue = char1 + char2 + char3 + char4
               let fullEpochValue = "17" + String(deviceValue) + "0000"
                if let fullEpochValueToInt = TimeInterval(fullEpochValue){
                  let savedDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: fullEpochValueToInt)
                      let now = Date()
                      let calendar = Calendar.current
                      let difference = calendar.numberOfDaysBetween(savedDate, and: now)
                          if difference > 2 {
                            //do something if greater than 2 days
                          }
                         }
                        }
                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
              }
          }
      }
  }



Do you think there is anything to improve upon or not really?

Why not loop over indices and then have a switch inside the loop for the index values you need to handle? I think such code will be much easier to handle

@JoakimDanielson good point, I knew it needed changes so I will do that thank you

One idea:
The easiest would be to use 4 character long hexadecimal numbers resulting in 65536 possibilities of days (179 years). Hex numbers have the advantage, that they are easy to work with and to convert.
Set a starting date, like The Epoch (1st January 1970), and calculate the days from thereon. Unix time based on The Epoch uses seconds since then, but as there are 86400 seconds in a day, it is easy to calculate the days and vice versa.
import time
import datetime

# gives the 4 character string of the day
a=hex(int(time.time()/86400))[2:] 
print(a) #19828 = 4D74h

# converting back
b=int(a,16)*86400
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(b).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) #'2024-04-15'

If that time range is not enough, you could use a 4 character long string to denote a certain day, then you have 26^4=456976 possibilities if you just use capital or lower letters. If you add numbers there are 36^4=1679616 possibilities, with upper and lower chars and numbers there are 62^4=14776336 possibilities (≈40000 years). However, the string-to-number conversions are more tricky and must be made up by yourself.
Note: The Unix timestamp has the Year 2038 Problem.
